# How to add PO Approval standard app to launchpad?

Tags: sap-fiori

I am configuring a fiori standard app- PO Approval for a client. We have the oData and the required services in " Service Catalog". Now we need to add the app to launchpad and we are following this link: "https://fioriappslibrary.hana.ondemand.com/sap/fix/externalViewer/#/detail/Apps('F0402A')/S9OP" but as I am new to this I am getting no idea of how do we create tiles, groups and catalogs. Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You use the SAP Fiori launchpad designer to manage catalogs, groups, and tiles.
To add the app to the Fiori Launchpad, there are also steps in backend required.

There is some documentation available [here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/cc1c7615ee2f4a699a9272453379006c/7.5.7/en-US/aebcf4b907ba419a867572405fe9e6c4.html)
and more general docu both [here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/cc1c7615ee2f4a699a9272453379006c/7.5.7/en-US/f951b50a07ce41deb08ced62711fe8b5.html) and [here](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/Fiori/SAP+Fiori+launchpad+-+Portal).

@stackoverflow admins:
I hope you accept above reference to docu.
The question is pretty general and a detailed answer would probably comprise too many pages.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply! Do I really need to create new tiles and catalog and groups for a standard app?

Comment: You might find [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=62HjQdTzG6A) helpful.

It explains several steps required in backend and frontend.
You can find it on youtube using search term “How to ADD SAP Fiori Launchpad”.

In your question you mentioned a link to the standard app in the Fiori Apps Library.
If you go there to tab  “IMPLEMENTATION INFORMATION”, you will find the already available Catalog, Group and Role.

Comment: Thanks for the information but I already have done that from the implement information and didn't get PO Approval  in "my inbox".

Comment: Do you see the corresponding Catalog and Group in the Launchpad designer?
Maybe a screenshot of Launchpad designer would be helpful that displays your current state?